# How to know which process died when monitoring two processes in while loop

Tags: powershell

I'm monitoring two processes on a server. when one of them dies, I need to know which one it was.

is there a better way to check this than what i have so far? Is there a way to do this without the if / elseif i have so far?

```
while ((ps proc1 -ov websrv).Responding -and (ps proc2 -ov connec).Responding) 
{ sleep -m 100 }

$pmsname = if (!$websrv.Responding -and !$connec.Responding) { "beide" }
            elseif (!$websrv.Responding -and $connec.Responding) { "websrv" }
            elseif ($websrv.Responding -and !$connec.Responding) { "connec" }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$status = [int]$websrv.Responding + [int]$connec.Responding * 2

$pmsname = switch ($status) {
  0 { 'keiner' }
  1 { 'websrv' }
  2 { 'connec' }
  3 { 'beide' }
  default { throw "unrecognized status: $status" }
}
```

Casting the value of the `Responding` property to an integer gives you a value of 1 if the process is responding, and 0 if it isn't. By multiplying that number with 2 for the second process you make the "responding" status of the two processes distinguishable from each other, so that you can add the values and use a [`switch`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx) statement for determining the overall status.

Answer (score 3):

Ansgar's answer should work perfectly fine, but is a bit esoteric for production scripts in my opinion.

Something like this will just check each process in turn to ensure they're running, which is more readable and also allows you to adjust the number of processes much easier.

```
$Processes = ("dwm","explorer","fakeproc")

while ($true){
    foreach ($ProcName in $Processes){
        $Proc = Get-Process $ProcName -ea SilentlyContinue
        if ($Proc -eq $null -or !$Proc.Responding){
            Write-Host "Process '$($ProcName)' Not Responding" -Fore Red
        }
    }
    Sleep 1
}
```